# If the world caught on fire how long would it take to burn?

Tags: science-based, fire

If one forest fire couldn't be contained and it spread across the world how long do you think it would take for 90% of the world to catch on fire, burn, and then burn out?

Also, while the world was burning how hot would the worlds atmosphere get and how would that affect human survivability (assuming that there were survivors from this mass fire)?

Comment: Most of the world is water. Last I check water doesn't burn. Did you mean 90% of the land?

Comment: There are many islands and continents that are disconnected. How do you expect a single fire to spread between them?

Comment: What about places like Antartica or the Saraha desert that are composed of stuff that doesn't burn?

Comment: Look at a map.  There are too many natural firebreaks.  I think if you want to burn the world you need to start with something from space, like the dinosaur killer asteroid.

Comment: A couple of assumptions here seem false as well - I would anticipate that, like a volcanic eruption, the forest fires would make the world _cooler_, not hotter, at least in the short term, as the smoke and ash dim the sun.  Also, "couldn't be contained" is relative; the effort expended would be in proportion to the threat.  If there were a serious risk of 90% of the world burning, you can bet forests would be felled and cleared.

Comment: Centralia, PA was built over a coal mine. The coal caught fire about 60 years ago, and it's estimated that there's enough fuel for 200 years.

Comment: Just a comment: Fires are often extinguished by themselves because all the humidity inside the wood goes into the air (the heat also vaporizes water), builds towering clouds (even thunderstorms) and finally the rain coming down kills the fire. It can happen that it is not working because strong winds are drifting the clouds away, but alone that is normally sufficient that fires go out even when further material is available.

Answer (score 2):

According to some theories, the biggest fires in the history of our planet happened during the Ordovician period - peat fires about the size of Australia. At that time life could not very well ingest wood, so dead plants accumulated in giant peat deposits. A low level of oxygen made starting of a fire very unlikely and it burned slowly.

In modern world fire just cannot become this big - with higher levels of oxygen it starts much more often and fuel for it cannot accumulate over big territories.